# xmodmap confusion betwen AltGR and Left Control

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, xmodmap

I'm having trouble making <kbd>AltGr</kbd> work on ubuntu so I can type 3rd level characters (@£§,{[],etc)
it so happens that <kbd>RCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>RAlt</kbd> don't work either so I have no way of typing such characters.

My <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> seems mapped to the same as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (<kbd>Altgr</kbd> is mapped to both 108 and 64), 64 being <kbd>RControl</kbd>.

Here's the problem, if I change the mapping to get <kbd>AltGr</kbd> printing @'s, I have to map 64 to Mode_switch. If I do that I lose the ability of using <kbd>RControl</kbd> to <kbd>Control_R</kbd>, so no more control shortcuts, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.

I either have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or '@'s', and I need both.
Is there a way to fix this, maybe mapping <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> to another keymap?